# use URL to get smart TV UID via TV browser, then pass UID to server for processing and return content to display

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, restful-url, smart-tv

not sure if this had been done before, but basically i had a project that requires me to display some custom content via URL onto a display device like a display screen using a mini pc. we have a cms on our server and the device is on the client's site, the flow is to get a UID of the device, register and validate it in the cms, then display the content on the client's device.

previous implementation was installing php and hosting onto the mini pc, run the URL on the mini pc browser and use php to retrieve the UID and pass it to the server to be registered and validated in the cms. however this process is too troublesome and time consuming because of setting up php and installing hosting on the mini pc, especially if the client wants to have a lot of display devices.

so the new requirement is to just run a url on the device browser, and it will retrieve the device UID and pass to cms. this is much easier and more scalable as future clients may use like smart tv instead of display screen with mini pc, so there's no need to install php and hosting( im not even sure if its possible to do that onto a smart tv).

however from my research so far there's no real solution to implement this flow, either because im not searching correctly for what i need, or it really is not possible and a workaround is needed, although my network engineer colleague insists that it can be done. and since there's plenty of smart tv brands, i'd probably have to build my own custom APIs (mentioned by my colleague) or something and hopefully its not too intensive/difficult.

project is due in one month and im cracking my head, appreciate any help or suggestion provided.

ps: im building my cms using codeigniter 3

Comment: Each SmartTV vendor will have its own way for fetching DUID. LG -http://webostv.developer.lge.com/api/webos-service-api/device-unique-id/, Samsung - https://developer.samsung.com/smarttv/develop/api-references/samsung-product-api-references/productinfo-api.html.
Other manufacturers share their SDK/Documentation when you contact them as developer/partner.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Tizen based Smart TV then you can simply fetch UID using webapis     `<script type="text/javascript" src="$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js"></script>`
and then simply calling `webapis.productinfo.getDuid()` by this you will get the UID then you can pass it on to any function to verify it from CMS.